# How to upload nested directories and files into s3 bucket using python boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a folder called *to be uploaded* inside which I have files, folders, and nested folders/nested directories.

Whatever ever I want to upload into the s3 bucket, I just put it into the *to be uploaded* folder and run a python3 script, after which I have to get all the things inside *to be uploaded* folder as it is inside the s3 bucket.

Below pics are for reference as to just get an idea of how my *to be uploaded* folder looks like

[image: 1]

[image: Folder Structure]

[image: Folder Structure]

I have set up all the aws configuration stuff using boto3 but got stuck here So, I'd like to see a python user-defined/pre-defined function after running which I can get all the contents in the *to be uploaded* folder as shown in the first picture into the s3 bucket as it is.

I am using windows 10 os and python 3.9.2 interpreter.

Please help !!!

Any help is highly appreciated !!!!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not sure what is the issue. You haven't shown any python script nor explained what's wrong with it.

Comment: @ Marcin I haven't written any python script yet, instead I am just asking for a python code snippet with dynamic values as of now that could solve my problem

Comment: So start writing _something_, and ask _specific_ questions about the part that you don't understand.

Comment: The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (`cp` or `sync`) can copy the files quite easily. Do you specifically need to write your own code to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

params is a file in which you have the access keys and other confidential stuff in a,b,c,d variables

```
import os, boto3, params, subprocess

os.environ['aws_access_key_id'] = params.a
os.environ['aws_secret_access_key'] = params.b
os.environ['default_region_name'] = params.c
os.environ['default_output_format'] = params.d



def upload_to_s3():
    subprocess.run(
        ['aws', 's3', 'sync', './folder-name', 's3://bucket-name'])


upload_to_s3()
```